# How to capture part of the screen in OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, screenshot

In Snow Leopard I could easily capture a part of the screen using [this](http://www.chimoosoft.com/products/captureme/), but it does not work anymore with OS X Lion, so I wonder if you know any other approach to capture *a part* of the screen (a rectangular selection) in OS X Lion?

Comment: ok, preview will do the trick for less euros: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/07/capture-save-screen-shots-with-preview-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: I want to close the question and give somebody the points. Anybody wants to copy my auto-answer?

Comment: So wait a second — flow, did you want to make a **screen shot** all along? The link you posted only talks about **images**, not **videos**. Why don't you accept the answer that is already there (it tells you the same thing as in the link).

Comment: sorry, I was talking about static screen capture, nothing to do with movies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift-Cmd-4

Drag the rectangle and it writes a PNG to the desktop

Shift-Cmd-3 does the whole screen. But these are for still screen shots, not recording as a movie, if that's what you really meant.